# Is there a term for "this month last year" in a report?

Tags: visualization, databases, terminology

I'm building a report that has month over month data, but also "this month last year". Is there a better/standard way of describing this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question probably belongs on the english langage stack site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Same period last year** is what you want.

BTW, your question does not appear to be about data science.

### References

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634972.aspx

http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s2477/same-period-previous-year.htm

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see a suitable SE network property to post this to; apologies.